# Joint distribution of dependent Gaussians and their product

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Consider a pair of dependent zero mean unit variance Gaussians, $$X,Y \sim \mathcal{MVN}\left(\vec{0},\begin{pmatrix}1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1\end{pmatrix}\right).$$
Their product $Z:=X\cdot Y$ is known to follow the variance gamma distribuiton with density
$$p(z)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \exp\left[\frac{\rho z}{1-\rho^2}\right] K_{0}\left[\frac{\vert z\vert}{1-\rho^2}\right],$$ where $K_0$ is the order zero modified Bessel function of the second kind (see [Nadaraja and Pogány, 2016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.crma.2015.10.019)).

**Is the joint distribution of $X,Y,Z$ known?**

The distribution of $W:=aX +bY+cZ$ is also of interest.

Comment: Cross posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385973/joint-distribution-of-dependent-gaussians-and-their-product